# Dependent types: Vector of vectors

Tags: coq, dependent-type, idris

I'm new to dependent types (I'm trying both Idris and Coq, despite their big differences).

I'm trying to express the following type: *given a type T and a sequence of k nats n1, n2, ... nk, a type consisting of k sequences of T with length n1, n2, ... nk respectively*.

That is, a vector of k vectors, whose lengths are given by a parameter.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a heterogeneous list, as follows.

```
Require Vector.
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive hlist {A : Type} (B : A -> Type) : list A -> Type :=
| hnil : hlist B []
| hcons : forall a l, B a -> hlist B l -> hlist B (a :: l).

Definition vector_of_vectors (T : Type) (l : list nat) : Type :=
  hlist (Vector.t T) l.
```

Then if `l` is your list of lengths, the type `vector_of_vectors T l` with will the type you describe.

For example, we can construct an element of `vector_of_vectors bool [2; 0; 1]`:

```
Section example.
  Definition ls : list nat := [2; 0; 1].

  Definition v : vector_of_vectors bool ls :=
    hcons [false; true]
          (hcons []
                 (hcons [true] hnil)).
End example.
```

This example uses some notations for vectors that you can set up like this:

```
Arguments hnil {_ _}.
Arguments hcons {_ _ _ _} _ _.

Arguments Vector.nil {_}.
Arguments Vector.cons {_} _ {_} _.

Delimit Scope vector with vector.
Bind Scope vector with Vector.t.
Notation "[ ]" := (@Vector.nil _) : vector.
Notation "a :: v" := (@Vector.cons _ a _ v) : vector.
Notation " [ x ] " := (Vector.cons x Vector.nil) : vector.
Notation " [ x ; y ; .. ; z ] " :=  (Vector.cons x (Vector.cons y .. (Vector.cons z Vector.nil) ..)) : vector.

Open Scope vector.
```

Comment: Or you can `Import Vector.VectorNotations.`

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, `VectorNotations` has a bug where the notation for Vector.nil is declared as `[]` instead of `[ ]`, which is how it's declared for List.nil. This confuses Coq into thinking `[]` is a token rather than two separate tokens and interferes with my use of `[]` for List.nil. So I've gotten in the sad habit of never importing `VectorNotations`. This bug is fixed in master, so I will get to unlearn this habit someday.

Comment: It looks like they fixed it for Coq 8.6.1.

Answer (score 5):

In Idris, besides creating a custom inductive type, we can reuse the standard type of heterogeneous vectors -- [`HVect`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/b352960b4b70146ebd6b748f7ed4093786a5c5c8/libs/base/Data/HVect.idr):

```
import Data.HVect

VecVec : Vect k Nat -> Type -> Type
VecVec shape t = HVect $ map (flip Vect t) shape

val : VecVec [3, 2, 1] Bool
val = [[False, False, False], [False, False], [False]] -- the value is found automatically by Idris' proof-search facilities
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, here is a solution in Idris inspired by the one posted by James Wilcox:

```
module VecVec

import Data.Vect

data VecVec: {k: Nat} -> Vect k Nat -> (t: Type) -> Type where
    Nil : VecVec [] t
    (::): {k, n: Nat} -> {v: Vect k Nat} -> Vect n t -> VecVec v t -> VecVec (n :: v) t

val: VecVec [3, 2, 3] Bool
val = [[False, True, False], [False, True], [True, False, True]]
```

This example uses the automatic translation of bracketed lists to the basic constructors `Nil` and `::` of whatever data type defines them.

Comment: You could've also used a list as the index of the `VecVec` type, since you don't really use the variable `k`: `data VecVec : List Nat -> Type -> Type where
  Nil : VecVec [] t
  (::) : Vect n t -> VecVec v t -> VecVec (n :: v) t`.